# How to cleanup events and attached objects from DOM elements before Intercooler.JS removes them?

Tags: javascript, dom, code-cleanup, intercooler.js

I have a static server-side generated form made in Laravel that I'm trying to add Intercooler.js to. In this form I apply input masks to some text fields, using a javascript library. Without Intercooler, after the form is submitted the page is redirected and all DOM objects from that page are destroyed by the browser so I don't have to care about cleaning up.

With Intercooler.js and other frameworks alike, there is no page reload. Instead the content of the page is swapped and the DOM objects are removed from the page, but since they could still be attached to other objects and events, they could still be in memory.

So my question is: Where do I hookup my cleaning code in Intercooler.js? I understand that **Intercooler.ready(function(elt))** exists, but according to the docs, I only receive the new elements being added, not the old ones. It doesn't give me the opportunity to cleanup anything attached to the elements being removed.

I read through the documentation, and couldn't find anything that I could use for this.

Answer (score 0):

I asked about this in the Gitter community. In order to cleanup code before the element is removed you should listen to the **beforeSwap.ic** event. To simplify its use I create a function inspired in how turbolinks, stimulus and unpoly handle this situation.

```
const compiler = function(selector, fn) {
  Intercooler.ready(function(elt) {
    let cleanupFn;
    const $el = $(elt).find(selector);

    if ($el.length > 0) {
      cleanupFn = fn($el);
    }

    // Cleanup
    $(document).on("beforeSwap.ic", function(e) {
      const el = e.target;

      //Check if the element selected is inside the element being swapped
      if ($(el).find(selector).length > 0) {
        if (cleanupFn) cleanupFn();
      }
    });
  });
};

export default compiler;
```

And here is an example using it:

```
compiler("form.userForm", elt => {
    const im = new Inputmask("999.999.999-99");
    const inputCpf = $("input[name=cpf]")[0];
    im.mask(inputCpf);

    return () => {
      if (inputCpf.inputmask) inputCpf.inputmask.remove();
    };
  });
```

When you call the **compiler** function, you pass the CSS selector from the element you want to monitor. When that element enters the page, he is selected via jQuery and passed to the callback provided.

For cleaning up, you return a function from the callback which will be called before the selected element is removed.